# Nested scroll view set Disable not working

Tags: android-layout

Respected Android Programmer,

I am facing the one major problem is that nested scroll view not get disable. Here I am using RecylerView  inside the Nested ScrollView.

Actually I am using the so many fragments in one Activity so when default recylerview loaded the listing user the Nested Scrolview now i have to click on floating button i have to hide the that fragment with with trance parent layout or frame layout. Its done but now problem is that when i use all function of recycler like

NestedScrollView mScrollView;
 mScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Not working may i know the reason.

Best
Romesh Chand

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide us a little more information or maybe some additional code so that your fellow SO members can better help? Your question is pretty vague without it. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I have to make nested scrollview lock means once load the recyclerview we want to lock the scrolling. So in simple way not nested scrollview locking function not worked. If you want code then in morning I can share you but just Nested scrolling listener not working i am also shocked to see this.

Comment: mScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); its not working when we have make nested scrolling false.

Comment: xml <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

Comment: <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

Comment: mScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mScrollView.setClipChildren(false);
        recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycler, false);

Comment: I am also using androidx